# Where can I download Visual Sourcesafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Where can I download Microsoft Visual Sourcesafe?
I use MS Visual Studio 2010.

Is this software free or must pay to use it?
I try to google but no download page is at Microsoft's site

Comment: Why do you need it? Visual SourceSafe is no longer maintained (mainline support ended in 2012, extended support ends in 2017). It is no longer shipped since MSVS 2010.

Comment: there are some old projects using this software..

Comment: I recommend you use another source control software such as GIT, Subversion or Mercurial

Comment: Using a newer product won't access the information needed in SourceSafe ... to move to another product. One needs VSS just to extract the assets.

Answer (score 6):

I just got this ISO from [the-eye](https://the-eye.eu/public/MSDN/Visual%20SourceSafe%202005/).

Comment: May save the day to anybody who is still using VSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[I found this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe)

> With Visual Studio 2010, Microsoft no longer distributes Visual
>   SourceSafe. Microsoft now offers Team Foundation Server Basic for
>   smaller development teams. There is a hotfix so existing SourceSafe
>   customers can use SourceSafe with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why the sad smiley? After being forced to use VSS for more than an hour I am more than happy that it was buried by MS!

Comment: Im moving backwards on this current project.  So you are telling me I have to install VS2010 and I can't use VS2013 with VSS??  :-(